# Yii breaks when moving to different hostname

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

I've been developing a new interface for a website and I have setup the following virtual host under apache2:

> **blueseum.192.168.1.222.xip.io**

And everything works fine... the call to the rest api I have for displaying the front page and the other links in the nav section.

However, when I open the port forwarding to the site from outside and I setup my dyndns to include the site, none of the links work. The `/about` and `/contact` both come up as:

> **page not found on this site**

I am currently using `Yii 2.0 basic template`, but I am thinking of moving to the `Yii 2.0 advanced template` to see if this will sort out the issue.

If anyone can come up with a solution, that would be great!

Comment: Is the "page not found" error produced by Yii, or by your web server?

Comment: It appears to be by the webserver... I originally thought that it might be a path error, but everything seems to be find that way.

Comment: You're probably using another hostname to get to your server from the outside. Just add it to your virtual host config. Is it Apache or Nginx?

Comment: I've already setup a separate virtual host file under apache2 for the external hostname. I have even added it to my hosts file. I can access the site from externally, but none of the controller links work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find out what the issue was.

Even though I had set the

```
AllowOverride all
```

option in my virtual host file, it turns out that in the **apache.conf** file, the option was set to none. I changed it to all, reloaded the server and away it went.

Thanks to anyone who was trying to find the answer to this question.